# How to keep row in multiple mysql databases in sync? Preferably with doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, ubuntu, doctrine

What is, if there is, a good way to keep a row in to separate databases (possibly on different machines) in sync?

For clarity. I have multiple mysql databases who share a user table with the same schema. There is a "master" database that has it's own unique schema, but contains the user table which contains all user records. Then there are multiple "slave" databases who for the most part share the same schema, that also contains the user table (with the same schema) with stores a subset of user records.

When an update is made to an instance of the user record in any database I want that change propagated to too all instances of that user record in all databases it is in.

I'm using mysql, php5.3, and doctrine 1.2.x for an orm, running on ubuntu VPS servers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to do this using PHP or Doctrine: look to [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) to keep the slave database tables in synch with the master

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) and in specific, the [`replicate-do-table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table) configuration option to restrict the slave databases to only caring about specific table(s) from the master.

Comment: would this allow me to write directly to the slaves and have it propagate to the master? and vice-vera?

Comment: Doing that would require what's called a multi-master replication loop.  Server A would be master to server B, which would be master to server C, which would be master to server A.  It can be extended throughout the rest of the alphabet, but can be finicky to manage and maintain.  [This article from 2006](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html) still seems to be pretty accurate, and covers the sticky issues with autoincrement.

Comment: To be clear, my employer uses multi-master in production to keep a local application in sync with a version at another site.  Until the past 2-3 years, MySQL frequently corrupted the binary log, which requires some major manual reconstructive effort.  While multi-master is *possible*, unless you have full-time monitoring available, you may be in for a world of pain.  Replication errors happen every 2-3 months now, with random bouts of illogical and unreproducible SQL errors halting the loop.  I'm not sure if it's our fault, OpenVPN's fault, or MySQL's fault.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a path we're willing to go down. As for straight forward `replicate-do-table` I've done some light skimming on the issue, I'm not completely clear how this would work with replicating the entire `user` table the master to the slave. Am I mistaken?